# I want to display only one row per subject_id without using DISTINCT. Not sure how to go about it

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Ouput of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj9sn.jpg)I am working with a large amount of data so DISTINCT freezes the database

I have tried DISTINCT already on pgAdmin, no luck as of now.

```
SELECT p.subject_id,
    p.gender,
    p.dob,
    d.icd9_code, 
    pro.seq_num,
    pro.icd9_code,
    inpc.itemid inputevents,
    inp.itemid inputevents_mv,
    lab.itemid labevents,
    outp.itemid outputevents
FROM mimiciii.patients p

INNER JOIN mimiciii.diagnoses_icd d
    ON p.subject_id = d.subject_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.procedures_icd pro
    ON p.subject_id = pro.subject_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.labevents lab
    ON p.subject_id = lab.subject_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.inputevents_cv inpc
    ON p.subject_id = inpc.subject_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.inputevents_mv inp
    ON p.subject_id = inp.subject_id
INNER JOIN mimiciii.outputevents outp
    ON p.subject_id = outp.subject_id
WHERE d.icd9_code = '4299'
```

I keep getting a repeating value of subject_id.

Comment: When you say you've tried `DISTINCT` do you mean `DISTINCT <column_list>` or have you also tried `DISTINCT ON (subject_id) <column_list>`? `DISTINCT` selects distinct combinations of the column list, `DISTINCT ON` will apply the distinct rules to a specific column or columns rather than the entire select list.

Comment: Also, the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ... would help.

Comment: I added the output of the database with a picture.. So any form of DISTINCT gives me impossible loading times that never end. So I am trying to display unique values for every row of the first column. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: From the sample data you posted it seems that the repeating value of subject_id is caused by the join of the table mimiciii.labevents. If you need the column lab.itemid labevents then you will have all these duplicates.

Comment: The rows you added are not duplicates so DISTINCT wouldn't help.  DISTINCT ON could help.  Otherwise, don't join to labevents or join to just one row in labevents.

Comment: Or if you need `labevents`, you can get the multiple values in an array. Don't store the data like that though (that would break normal form)...only for viewing. Ex: `array_agg(lab.itemid) labevents` with `GROUP BY p.subject_id`

Comment: So I understand there are duplicates. I just want one row with the first column and progress to the next row without repeating the first column over. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: The question is which row is valid? In your example output the first row has `subject_id=852` and `labevents=50979`; the second row with the same `subject_id` has `labevents=51222`. Which row do you choose? Always the first one? See if this will help you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8b5e6da521f02ce8106e0048f69e1f97

Answer (score 0):

The output its correct because you have many "labevents" for the same "subject_id".

If you want tho get all those data, you always will get multiples lines.

If you want just the "patients" data, you can use a subquery, like a EXISTS to get the correct filter..

Some like that...

```
SELECT [p...] from patients p where exists (select 1 from ... where p.subject_id=d.subject_id )
```

=]

Comment: So I understand there are duplicates. I just want one row with the first column and progress to the next row without repeating the first column over. Not sure if that is possible.

Comment: @AndrewSalazar  There aren't duplicates, though.  You will need to decide what data to ignore.

Comment: I guess you should remove lab.itemid labevents from the select clause and the join with table lab.